# AWT Color Chooser

Tags: java, awt, jcolorchooser

I have a simple question. Are there any method calls to have a Color Chooser, like in java swing

```
(JColorChooser)
```

In Java `Awt`?

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.  `JColorChooser` is one of those reasons, AWT has no equivalent.